# TI-Nspire CX CAS double integral leaving variables in answer

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, calculator

I recently purchased the TI-Nspire CX CAS, and when performing certain integrals it seems to spit out an answer still containing variables. For example, when my input is:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 xe^{-(x+xy)} \, dy \, dx$$

the calculator gives the result as:

$$e^{-xy}(1-2e^{-1})$$

Similarly, if I input only the inner integral, I get:

$$\int_0^1 xe^{-(x+xy)} \, dy = xe^{-x-xy}$$

Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior? Wolfram Alpha doesn't have an issue with this integral. Thanks!

Comment: I know how to do double integrals on the calculator, and most of them work perfectly fine. This is the only one I've come across so far that has this sort of result I can't tell why it's the case.

Comment: Could it be that you have to write the product $xy$ as `x*y`? Maybe the calculator interprets `xy` as a variable?

Comment: That turned out to be the issue, thanks so much! I had figured that out in some other cases, but I somehow overlooked it here. Thanks again!